# Get current tab of DefaultTabController

Tags: flutter

In the onPressed for my fab, I want to know the index of the tab that is currently selected in my DefaultTabController.  How do I do this?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'pari',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: widget._themeData,
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: widget._tabs.length,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('pari'),
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs: widget._tabs,
            ),
          ),
          body: _buildBody(),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: addWagerTap,
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share your addWagerTap function and the rest of your widget code? Assuming this is a Stateful Widget?

Comment: addWagerTap is empty at the moment.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you wrap your `Scaffold` inside of a `Builder`, you'll be able to access your `DefaultTabController` within the proper `context`. You can then retrieve the tab index with `DefaultTabController.of(context).index`.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'pari',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: widget._themeData,
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('pari'),
              bottom: TabBar(
                  isScrollable: true,
                  tabs: [Text('0'), Text('1'), Text('2'), Text('3')]),
            ),
            body: _buildBody(),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(
                    'Current Index: ${DefaultTabController.of(context).index}');
              },
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It worked for me when I needed to change the tab index programmatically as below
`onPressed: () {
                            DefaultTabController.of(context).index =2;
                          }),`

Comment: Anyone know how I can change the indicator using this method? I can't seem to get it to work although pressing a button will display the correct index

Comment: I'm not sure if it's only me, but when swiping fast and clicking on the fab. It would return the wrong index, could be that the swipe event have not completed yet?

Answer (score 7):

You can also get the index of the tab by using the onTap property of the DefaultTabController.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
    title: 'pari',
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: widget._themeData,
    home: DefaultTabController(
      length: widget._tabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('pari'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            onTap: (int index) {
               print('index is $index');
             }
            tabs: widget._tabs,
          ),
        ),
        body: _buildBody(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: addWagerTap,
        ),
      )
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the user changes tab by swiping

Comment: An answer that addresses swiping as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55742228/how-can-i-detect-that-a-tabbarview-has-just-been-dragged