# How can I detect that a TabBarView has just been dragged?

Tags: dart, flutter

The TabBar widget has an onTap() callback that allows to detect when the user has just pressed a tab. This is useful so that we we can prepare the new tabView to show some dynamic data.

The TabBar widget has also a drag functionality that allows to change the tabView displayed ( similar result as tapping on another tab). But in this case there seems to be no way to prepare the new TabView because there's no an onDrag() callback.

So the question is : is there a way to detect that a TabBarView has just been dragged?

Answer (score 13):

I've found this solution to distinguish between a tapping on a new tab and swiping to a new tab events.

It looks very awkward but it's working. It's a pity that is that is not possible to detect the beginning of the swipe.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    print("FB:X _HNPageState:initState()");
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: _myTabs.length);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      if (_tabController.indexIsChanging)
        // Tab Changed tapping on new tab
       onTabTap();
      else if(_tabController.index != _tabController.previousIndex)
        // Tab Changed swiping to a new tab
        onTabDrag();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

Previous answers only consider when user finished dragging.

In case if you need to listen for more accurate data (i.e. user has just started dragging) you can to listen for animation:

```
_tabController.animation.addListener(() => print(_tabController.animation.value.toString));
```

Comment: Sorry but doesn't works for me.

Getting outputs as 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0

Dosen't tell, how much % of swipe is done.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
int _tab = 0;

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();

 _tabController = TabController(
  length: _tabs.length, 
  vsync: this
 );

 _tabController.animation!.addListener(_tabListener);
}

void _tabListener(){
 if(_tab != _tabController.animation!.value.round()){
  setState(() {
   _tab = _tabController.animation!.value.round();
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: To get the exact value, I removed the .round(). because I was looking for % of tabController moved. Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue, and this work for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [TabController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabController-class.html) and add a listener to watch the changes. It works for tap and drag events/actions.

You can do something like this:

```
_tabController.addListener(() {
    print("${_tabController.index}");
});
```

Comment: that detects both tab taps and swipe. I need to differentiate between them

Comment: Do you really need to make different actions when tap or drag?

Comment: If you need to disable one of the tabs, be aware of [this bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31206)

Comment: I need to treat them differently because the drag generates 2 events on the _tabController ( one for drag started and another for drag ended). In my event handler I need to load ( only once) the elements of the new tabView. BTW y have renamed the second handler to  onTabDrag because it actually does different things

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Solution;

```
 if (_tabController.indexIsChanging || 
    (_tabController.animation.value == _tabController.index)) {
  print(_tabController.index);

  Provider.of<OrderScreenProvider>(context, listen: false).onIndexChangeResetAccountInfo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case; tab drag changes not handle with tabcontroller before I setted it to as TabView controller.

Handle like this;

```
void _handleTabSelection() {
    if (_tabController.indexIsChanging || _tabController.index != _tabController.previousIndex) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedTab = _tabController.index;
      });
    }
  }
```

And set it;

```
TabBarView(
   controller: _tabController,
   ...



TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
    ...
```